# how to add and remove textfield in button action?

Tags: uitextfield, swift4

[image]

I am using tableview method is not convenient for my functionality.

Functionality: when I click the plus button create new textfield with plus Button. But previous textfield Plus button is changed to minus button. when I click the minus button particular textfield is remove.
if I tried using tableview lot of errors will be there.

please help me! how can I create this functionality!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know this is correct way to do that but you can get similar thing that you want to achieve.

Declare HomeVC in UITableViewCell

```
class TextFieldCell: UITableViewCell {

    var home: HomeVC?

    //Add textfield
    //Add "addDeleteButton" for adding and removing

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        //Add target for "addDeleteButton"
        addDeleteButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(handleAddDelete), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc func handleAddDelete() {
        //Pass UITableViewCell as parameter
        home?.update(forCell: self)
    }
}
```

Assign home controller from cellForRow like below

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! TextFieldCell
    cell.home = self

    if indexPath.row == attractions.count - 1 {
        //Set background image for adding(plus) to addDeleteButton
    } else {
        //Set background image for remove(minus) to addDeleteButton
    }
    return cell
}
```

Add this function for adding/removing cell in HomeVC

```
func update(forCell: TextFieldCell) {

    let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: forCell)

    if indexPath?.row == attractions.count - 1 {

        //Set background image for remove(minus) to addDeleteButton
        forCell.addDeleteButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named:"minus"), for: .normal)

        attractions.append(attractions[0])
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.insertRows(at: [[0,attractions.count-1]], with: .automatic)
        tableView.endUpdates()
    } else {
        attractions.remove(at: (indexPath?.row)!)
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .automatic)
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Happy coding...!